# Failure to print an "X" pattern using loop

Tags: c

I am trying to print an "X" patern using the symbol "*". But the program is not working as I have expected. Expecting the help of the experts. Thanks in advance!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int sp1,sp2,space1,space2;

sp1=0;
sp2=3;

while((sp1<=3)||(sp2>=3))
{
    printf(" ");

    ++sp1;

    if(sp1>=3)
        --sp2;
    if(sp1!=0)
        printf("*");
    space1=7;
    space2=1;

    while((space1>1((space2>1)&&(space2<=7)))
{
printf(" ");

space1-=2;

if(space1<1)
    space2+=2;
printf("*\n");
}

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could treat it as a square matrix, where you want to print `*` in the positions that belong to the principal and secondary diagonals, and print space for any other position.

Comment: But isn't it possible to do the same using loops?

Comment: Yes, you would do 2 loops inside each other, if you consider a characters grid the first loop iterates over the lines of the grid (prints new line character at the end), and the second iterates over de columns (prints each character in the grid), then you just have to check the conditions for the positions (line, column) that are in the diagonals of the grid and print `*`, or else print space for any position that are not in the diagonals.

Comment: Have you worked with arrays and matrices yet? You will do the exact same thing when working with matrices. Note that the positions in the principal diagonal of a matrix have equal indexes for line and column, and the positions in the secondary diagonal of a matrix are such that the sum of the indexes of the line plus the column plus 1 is equal to the total number of columns (= length of the line = size of 1 dimension of the square matrix).

Comment: I actually skipped the matrix part.